# How to query a key via a variable?

Tags: javascript, object, syntax

I want to set the value of a JSON key by a variable to `setCache` with the star and then the function sets the key value in the JSON object cache.

I have code it how I think it makes sense, however I know this is wrong because `star` is not in the object.

I also thought of using template strings.

### My code

```
var cache = {
    "capricorn": "this should be null",
    "aquarius": "null",
    "pisces": "null",
    "aries": "null",
    "taurus": "null",
    "gemini": "null",
    "cancer": "null",
    "leo": "null",
    "virgo": "null",
    "libra": "null",
    "scorpio": "null",
    "ophiuchus": "null",
    "sagittarius":"null"
}

function setCache(cache,star, value) {
    cache.star = value
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamically access object property using variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the subscript (`[]`) operator to refer to a property using a variable:

```js
cache[star] = value;
```

Comment: that works thanks :) I think I tried that but I had an underlying bug and I realized just now ;)